# build getting error with ios 9 version. libc++abi.dylib terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Tags: ios9, sigabrt

I am getting the following error while building app on IOS 9 devices.. No issues with older version ios. . Anyway to fix this issue .

see the error details 
the end of application launch'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183fc8f5c 0x198bbff80 0x183fc8e2c 0x184eb7f3c 0x1897c0688 0x1897bd2e4 0x18dd0f7ec 0x18dd0fb6c 0x183f805a4 0x183f80038 0x183f7dd38 0x183eacdc0 0x18958c0ac 0x189586f44 0x10007b154 0x1993ea8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);             Thread 1 signal SIGABRT
[pool release];
return retVal;
```

Comment: please add Exception breakpoint to catch the Line

Comment: *** Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3505.17/UIApplication.m:3294

Comment: That's still not the appropriate one.  You should quote the message which tells you the problem: "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch".  Please see the dupe for more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" error when running a project with Xcode 7, iOS 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884896/application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you problem will solve with this way :
Set your self.window.rootRootController after

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]

[window setRootViewController:viewController];
```

please see this link :

[“Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch” error when running a project with Xcode 7, iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884896/application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-a)

also :

[Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:],](http://%20%20%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711397/assertion-failure-in-uiapplication-runwithmainscenetransitioncontextcomplet)